# Destroy GameObject using Tag and Specific Location

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a tetris-like matching game. When three rows are matched, I want them to be destroyed. Each colored block has its own unique tag "GreenBlock" , "RedBlock" etc. I already have successfully made the game identified whenever three same-colored blocks are within each other.

To visualize the screen, I made a custom Grid System using GameObjects with BoxCollider 2d:

|   C1   |   C2   |   C3   |   C4   |   C5   |
|   B1   |   B2   |   B3   |   B4   |   B5   |
|   A1   |   A2   |   A3   |   A4   |   A5   |

Now, for example on A1-A2-A3, three green blocks were matched. Those green blocks have the same "GreenBlock" tag, alongside with all the green blocks on the screen. I only wanted to destroy the "GreenBlocks" tagged gameObjects on positions A1-A2-A3. I cannot just say delete all "GreenBlocks" tagged objects since it would delete all Green Blocks on the screen even if they are not matched. I cannot also do the "inspector method" (dragging items their manually on public variables before running the game) since all the blocks are generated randomly.

How can I delete those same-tagged objects on a specific location?

Comment: There are too many ways do that.I just share an idea for you.Use linecast from A to B get  RaycastHit2D[] results .check the results wheather have same tag.

Comment: @RonTang Thanks for the heads up about linecast! I'm still a bit naive about these stuffs, can you write a very basic code that'll give me an idea on how to implement it on those grids?

Comment: If unity Physics2D.Linecast not meet your need. You could read this:http://playtechs.blogspot.com/2007/03/raytracing-on-grid.html